# Non-symbolic variables in equation

Tags: matlab, equation

```
for theta=1:10
  x_3 = cos(theta);

  syms x;
  x_2 = 'x_3 - cos(x+theta)';

  a = solve(x_2,x)
end
```

When I run this code, the solutions for `a` include `x_3` and `theta` instead of substituting them with the values defined above. How can I solve this using the actual values of `x_3` and `theta`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem of mixing `syms` and strings?

Try:

```
syms x;
for theta = 1:10
    x_3 = cos(theta);
    x_2 = x_3 - cos(x+theta);
    a = solve(x_2,x)
end
```

or

```
for theta = 1:10
    x_3 = cos(theta);
    x_2 = 'x_3 - cos(x+theta)';
    a = solve(x_2,'x')
end
```

Comment: I cannot test it right now but i will come back to you as soon as I can, thanks already!